# BehaviorSubject 'grouped'

Tags: rxjs

I'm just getting started with RXJS to see if it can replace my currently manual data streams. One thing I'm trying to port is a situation whereby the last value in the stream is remembered, so future observers will always get the 'current' value as well as subsequent ones. This seems to be fulfilled by BehaviorSubject.

However, I need to do this for a group of entities. For example, I might have data that represents a message from a user:

```
{ userId: 1, message: "Hello!" }
```

And I want a BehaviorSubject-like object that'll store the last message for all users. Is this something I can do with RXJS out-of-the-box, or would I need to do it myself? (If so, any pointers would be appreciated).

EDIT: After some more thought, it perhaps seems logical to having an 'incoming' subject, an observer that updates a Map, and then a function which I can call which initialises an Observable from the map values, and merges with the incoming stream...?

Comment: What is the expected behavior on subscribe? Are all the objects collected into a single object? Or are you going to emit the latest state for each object?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how it should work, to be honest. On subscription I'd want all of the latest messages for all users, which would probably have to be emitted individually (so if there were four users, four messages would be individual emitted with their last message) and thereafter messages would be emitted as new ones arrive. This would be useful for rendering an initial list of 'current' messages for all users for example, even if this occurred after some messages had been received.

Comment: sounds like nice usecase for [`shareReplay`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md). But I'm not sure if you really want to pass `Infinity` there...

Answer (score 0):

I use RxJS with a redux-like state setup. I have a BehaviorSubject that holds the current state, and every time an event/action is fired that current state gets passed through functions that produce a new state, which the subject is subscribed to.

Here's a simplified version of what I use:

```
export default class Flux {

  constructor(state) {
    //all resources are saved here for disposal (for example, when hot loading)
    //this is just a flux dispatcher
    this.dispatcher = new rx.Subject(),
    // BehaviorSuject constructed with initial state
    this.state = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(state),
  }

  addStore(store, initialState, feature = store.feature) {
      this.dispatcher
        .share()
        // this is where the "reduction" happens. store is a reducer that 
        // takes an existing state and returns the new state
        .flatMap(({action, payload}) =>
            store(this.state.getValue(), action, payload))
        .startWith(initialState || {})
        .subscribe(this.state)
    );

    return this;
  }

  addActions(actions: rx.Subject) {
    // actions are fed to the dispatcher
    this.resources.push(actions.share().subscribe(this.dispatcher));
    return this;
  }

}
```

I create a global Flux object with manages state. Then, for every "feature" or "page" or whatever I wish I add actions and stores. It makes managing state very easy, and things like time-travel are something that are a given with Rx.